# how to find user input value in the dictionary and display them, if it exists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

```
MENU_PROMPT = "\nEnter 'a' to add a movie, 'l' to see your movies, 'f' to find a movie by title, or 'q' to quit: "
movies = []

# And another function here for the user menu
selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)

def movie_data():
    title = input("Enter the movie title: ")
    director = input("Enter the movie director: ")
    year = input("Enter the movie release year: ")

    movies.append({
        'title': title,
        'director': director,
        'year': year
    })


def display():
    print("movies =", end =" ")
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie['title'])


while selection != 'q':
    if selection == "a":
        movie_data()
    elif selection == "l":
        display()
    elif selection == "f":
        find = input("enter the movie title")
        if find in movies:
            print("movie found.", movies)
        else:
            print(f'No Such Movie, Named {find}, Found!, Try Other Movie Name.')
    else:
        print('Unknown command. Please try again.')

    selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)
```

**if the user inputs the f for finding the movie name in the movies dictionary then what do I write in the last elif function, can anyone explain it??**

I want - (userinput movie name) - avengers
output - match found! movie name - avengers, director - (what the userinputs) & year - (what the userinputs)

Comment: You're not asking the user for director or year input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a search function which iterates over each element in the list and searches for the title attribute in dictionary.

```
MENU_PROMPT = "\nEnter 'a' to add a movie, 'l' to see your movies, 'f' to find a movie by title, or 'q' to quit: "
movies = []

# And another function here for the user menu
selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)

def movie_data():
    title = input("Enter the movie title: ")
    director = input("Enter the movie director: ")
    year = input("Enter the movie release year: ")

    movies.append({
        'title': title,
        'director': director,
        'year': year
    })


def display():
    print("movies =", end =" ")
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie['title'])



def search(title):
    for i in range(len(movies)):
        if(movies[i]['title']== str(title)):
            return movies[i]

    return None

while selection != 'q':
    if selection == "a":
        movie_data()
    elif selection == "l":
        display()
    elif selection == "f":
        find = input("enter the movie title:")
        movie = search(find)
        if (movie):

            print("movie found:", movie)
        else:
            print(f'No Such Movie, Named {find}, Found!, Try Other Movie Name.')
    else:
        print('Unknown command. Please try again.')

    selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list with dictionaries that contain title, director and year keys. You can loop through the list and search a match for the title, assuming the user inputs the title:

```
movies.append({
    'title': "title",
    'director': "director",
    'year': "year"
})

for m in movies:
    if m.get('title').lower().find("title") > -1:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```